# How to Change the network adapter setting of a virtual machine running Win7 on a Xen Server?

Tags: virtual-machines, xenserver

I have a Xen server running on a linux debian, the Xen server runs some virtual machines that are service servers (Domain, Antivirus, Biostart, etc.) but there is one with Win7 that appears with the network adapter disabled which does not allow remote access to this virtual machine, my question is ... How can I enable the network adapter of this virtual machine if I can not enter ?. The virtual machine, manages it and runs a Xen server ...

Comment: `Xenserver running on a linux debian` No you don't, Citrix Xenserver is built on Centos. You probably have a Xen server running on Debian - the space in the middle is crucial :) You should probably correct the question tags.